# Jquery document.location.reload() doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, reload

I need to reload the page after I update my database via ajax. In my ajax post method, I have something like the following:

```
success: function (data) {
    ....(some code doesn't matter)
    document.location.reload();
    ....(some other code I wish to execute after document is reloaded)

}
```

However, the code after `reload()` will be executed first and then page will reload.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you "reload" the page, it does just that; it reloads the page as if it was the first time you came to the page. Can you not reset the page by returning whatever data you need to reset the page from your ajax call? You can then take that data and make any updates that are necessary using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When page is reloaded the code after `document.location.reload();` is executed on the old instance of page, not the reloaded one.

You will need to add a parameter to the current location and do onDocumentReady on a breach that tests the parameter on the document.location to add the code you want.
ex:

```
document.location = document.location.href + "?afterReload=true";


$(document).ready(function() {
  if ( window.location.search.substring(1) != '' ){
     //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: change "window.location.search.substring(1)"  to actually look for the query string you just made , not just any one

Comment: Ended, it was an example, you should not add "?afterReload=true" if you have parameter already. But for an example I think the idea was needed.

Comment: Thanks, dude. I am trying to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a reload, redirect the page and add a variable at the end

```
window.location.replace("http://example.com/yourpage.php?extravariable");
```

You can then add some code to check for the GET and run the javascript code if the get value is set.